# a question about the sum of $ e^{ikx}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, wolfram-alpha

I have a simple question.
Let $
S = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {e^{ikx} } 
$ using the typical trick , we also have 
$
S\left( {e^{ix}  - 1} \right) = e^{i\left( {n + 1} \right)x}  - e^{ix} 
$ and if $
\left( {e^{ix}  - 1} \right) \ne 0
$ we divide by it and we have:
$
S=\left( {1 - e^{inx} } \right)\frac{{e^{ix} }}
{{1 - e^{ix} }}
$ And I see that this limit if n goes to infinity does not exist, but Wolfram|Alpha says that it [converges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+%28e%5E%28ikx%29+%2Ck%3D1..infinity%29). 
The problem clearly is in the factor $
\left( {1 - e^{inx} } \right)
$ it goes to 0 :S? or something

Comment: You have a geometric series with common factor $e^{ix}$. You also (should!) know that $|e^{ix}|=1$; would you happen to remember how the geometric series behaves at the boundary of the region where it converges?

Comment: You are saying that $
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } e^{ixn}  = 0
$ ? =S!!

Comment: I haven't said anything about convergence (yet). What do you remember about the behavior of the geometric series at the boundary?

Comment: the geometric series converges iff the norm of the term is less than 1.

Comment: Yes. But since $|e^{ix}|=1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, then...

Comment: But Im not computing the sum of the absolute values :S I´m confused

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1804/discussion-between-susuk-and-j-m)

Comment: What do you mean by norm, then, if not the absolute value?

Answer (score 4):

When evaluating the sum, Wolfram Alpha makes the necessary assumptions so that the series converges. For example `Sum[x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]` evaluates to $1/(1-x)$. It is not mentioned that this is only valid for $|x| < 1$, but that doesn't mean $1 + 2 + 2^2 \ldots = -1$

Similarly, `Sum[Exp[i x k], {k, 1, Infinity}]` evaluates to $-1 + 1/(1 - e^{ix})$ under the assumption that $|e^{ix}| < 1$ or $\mbox{Imag}(x)>0$. If you want Mathematica to output the conditions necessary for convergence, you need the `GenerateConditions` flag, like this:

```
Sum[Exp[i x k], {k, 1, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Alpha. In Mathematica it evaluates to:
$$
    \mbox{ConditionalExpression} \left[-\frac{e^{i x}}{-1 + e^{i x}}, 
       e^{\mbox{Re}[i x]} < 1 \ \ \&\& \ \ e^{i x} \ne 1 \right]
$$
Since you didn't specify that $x$ must be real, it is assumed to be possibly complex. Alternatively, one can specify that $x$ is real with a statement like this:

```
Assuming[ Element[x, Reals], Sum[Exp[I k x], {k, 1, Infinity}] ]
```

As expected, this gives the error `Sum::div: Sum does not converge.`.

So, why doesn't Mathematica give the convergence conditions by default? Probably just because it results in a simpler output. (If one is really interested in finding the analytic continuation of a function, the convergence conditions don't matter.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x$ is real, Wolfram is wrong.